# $\sum_i x_i^2 > (\sum_i x_i \sum_j x_j)/|\{x_i\}|$?

Tags: inequality, summation

Is this true:

$$\sum_i x_i^2 > (\sum_i x_i \sum_j x_j)/|\{x_i\}$$

Where $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$. I believe it must be, because this result is used in the calculation of the online variance. But I am failing to see why that is the case.

EDIT:
My bad, the second term is divided by the cardinality of the set.

If we assume that the cardinality of the set is $N$, then the first summation has $N$ terms, and the second will have $1+2+3+..+N$, which is $N(N+1)/2$, but we are dividing by $N$, so it will have $(N+1)/2$ temrs

Comment: $$\sum_i x_i \sum_j x_j = \sum_i x_i^2 + \sum_{i\ne j} x_i x_j$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$1^2+1^2$ is not bigger than $(1+1)(1+1)$.

However, it is true that $n \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)^2$ whenever $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ are real numbers. This follows from expanding
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n \left(x_i - \frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n}{n}\right)^2 \geq 0.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to recognize that 
$$
(\sum_i x_i)^2 = x^TEx
$$
with $E\in\mathbb R^n$ the matrix with all entries equal to one. This matrix has eigenvalues $n$ and $0$. Hence
$$
x^Tx = \sum x_i^2 \ge n^{-1} x^TEx = n^{-1} 
(\sum_i x_i)^2
$$